# Jinja2 filter for URL pattern generation in flask views

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am developing a small Flask application to present data about Cinema. Each cinema has two categories associated with itself

1. Language - language of that cinema. E.g. English, French
2. Genre - E.g. Action, Comedy, Suspense

**User Case** - There is a Cinema named `Inception` which is in `English` language and falls under the genre of `Suspense`. I want build clean URL for the page of `Inception` cinema such as **projectdomain.com/english/suspense/inception**.

Currently I am doing it through `blueprint.context_processor`.

```
@blueprint.context_processor:
def cinema_processor():
    def clean_cinema_name(cinema):
        return '{0} / {1} / {2}'.format(cinema['language'], cinema['genre'],
cinema['name'])
```

But I want to do it in `jinja2` custom filter - which will be much easier I guess.

Please assist me in case anyone has already done such `jinja2` custom filtering.

So far you may safely assume - one cinema name will belong to only one language and genre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to solve the Jinja2 filter side of things.

server.py:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

def cinema_url(cinema):
    return '/%s/%s/%s' % ( 
            cinema['language'],
            cinema['genre'],
            cinema['name'],
            )

# Register this function as a Jinja2 filter
app.jinja_env.filters['cinema_url'] = cinema_url

@app.route('/')
def home():
    cinemas = [ 
            {'name': 'Movie1', 'language': 'English', 'genre': 'action'},
            {'name': 'Movie2', 'language': 'Spanish', 'genre': 'comedy'},
        ]
    return flask.render_template('home.html', cinemas=cinemas)

app.run()
```

templates/home.html:

```
h1>Home</h1>

{% for cinema in cinemas %}
<li>
{# make use of the filter to create your URL #}
<a href="{{cinema|cinema_url}}">{{cinema['name']}}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#registering-filters

Do you need help with the routing too?

Comment: could you please let me know the significance of `app.jinja_env.filters['cinema_url'] = cinema_url` line in your code ???